# Why does the MIPS stack pointer need to be kept double word aligned?

Tags: assembly, stack, mips, mips32

I have read this in a couple of places, but without fully understanding why. I understand why all instructions have to be word aligned to 4 bytes in MIPS32.

But then I read that **a stack frame needs to be a multiple of 8, because the stack pointer needs to be double word aligned**. Why?

I understand everything in the attached image, except the reason for adding empty space to pad the stack to a multiple of 8 bytes.

[image: Stack Frame]

EDIT: One source for where I read this was [here](http://acm.sjtu.edu.cn/w/images/d/db/MIPSCallingConventionsSummary.pdf), page 3, bullet 4. The other was Computer Organization & Design, 5th Edition, by Patterson and Hennessey, Appendix A.6, under the Procedure Call Example. However, it's pretty clear to me now I was mistaken to assume they were talking about MIPS32.

Comment: From MSDN: _"MIPS ISA I and II, running in 32-bit mode, mandates that the stack pointer and frame pointer addresses align on 4-byte boundaries. MIPS ISA III and up, running in 64-bit mode, mandates that the stack pointer and frame pointer addresses align on 8-byte boundaries."_ Otherwise, if you tried to push a 64-bit value onto the stack using `sd` you'd get an alignment error.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So this is meant simply as a precaution to potentially accommodate a 64-bit stack pointer address or return address? Even if we're running in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Are you sure the 32-bit MIPS requires 8-byte stack alignment at all? It sounds like Michael is saying the 8B requirement only applies in 64-bit mode.  However, 8B alignment would make it easy to store `double`-precision floats on the stack in 32-bit mode, so some ABIs might well require 8B stack alignment.  Anyway, please add a link to where you read this.

Comment: 32-bits MIPS does *not* require 8-byte stack alignment by any hardware reason to my knowledge. It's just part of the convention required to be able to push a `long long` at any time. The convention IMHO is only is there to provide a seamless upgrade path to 64-bit. SGI MIPS machines BTW require the stack to be aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: It is most likely a convention for performance, should be no hardware requirement, not sure how there could be really, the lower address bits would be ignored if it were a hardware requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MIPS architecture can only access data types in memory that are evenly aligned with their size.

*See MIPS Run* by Dominic Sweetman says on page 320:

> At the point where a subroutine is called, sp must be eight-byte-aligned, matching the alignment of the largest basic types - a `long long` integer, or a floating-point double. The eight-byte alignment is not required by 32-bit MIPS integer hardware, but it is essential for compatibility...

Thus, if you never try to push a `double` to the stack, you can very well live with 4-byte alignment on a 32-bit system. Whether your OS can, is another question, though.